# как в методе filter js отфильтровать слова в предложении

Tags: javascript

Не могу отфильтровать в массиве которое находиться объекты. Нужно количество задач, имеющих в названии слово "UI"

Что не так делаю?

```js
const tasks = [
{id: 234, title: 'Create user registration API', timeSpent: 4, category: 'Backend', type: 'task'},
{id: 235, title: 'Create user registration UI', timeSpent: 8, category: 'Frontend', type: 'task'},
{id: 237, title: 'User sign-in via Google UI', timeSpent: 3.5, category: 'Frontend', type: 'task'},
{id: 238, title: 'User sign-in via Google API', timeSpent: 5, category: 'Backend', type: 'task'},
{id: 241, title: 'Fix account linking', timeSpent: 5, category: 'Backend', type: 'bug'},
{id: 250, title: 'Fix wrong time created on new record', timeSpent: 1, category: 'Backend', type: 'bug'},
{id: 262, title: 'Fix sign-in failed messages', timeSpent: 2, category: 'Frontend', type: 'bug'}
];

let taskFilterUi = tasks.filter((elem) => {
  return elem.title === "UI";
});

let taskMapUI = taskFilterUi.map((task) => {
  return "Заголовок:" + "  " + task.title;
});

console.log(taskMapUI);
```

Comment: `elem.title === "UI"` - в массиве нет таких объектов

Comment: В массиве только есть объект `{title: "User sign-in via Google UI"}` к примеру этот мне нужно в предложение отфильтровать слова "UI"

не могу понять как сделать

Comment: Внизу -- ответ.

Comment: Да увидел, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const tasks = [
  {id: 234, title: 'Create user registration API', timeSpent: 4, category: 'Backend', type: 'task'},
  {id: 235, title: 'Create user registration UI', timeSpent: 8, category: 'Frontend', type: 'task'},
  {id: 237, title: 'User sign-in via Google UI', timeSpent: 3.5, category: 'Frontend', type: 'task'},
  {id: 238, title: 'User sign-in via Google API', timeSpent: 5, category: 'Backend', type: 'task'},
  {id: 241, title: 'Fix account linking', timeSpent: 5, category: 'Backend', type: 'bug'},
  {id: 250, title: 'Fix wrong time created on new record', timeSpent: 1, category: 'Backend', type: 'bug'},
  {id: 262, title: 'Fix sign-in failed messages', timeSpent: 2, category: 'Frontend', type: 'bug'}
];

let taskFilterUi = tasks.filter(elem => elem.title.indexOf("UI") != -1);
let taskMapUI = taskFilterUi.map(task => "Заголовок:" + "  " + task.title);
console.log(taskMapUI);
```

Answer (score 2):

Если искать слово - предполагается окружение пробельными символами, концом или началом строки(могут конечно и знаки препинания присутствовать).
`/(^|\s)UI($|\s)/.test( '... UI ...' )`

```js
const tasks = [
{id: 234, title: 'Create user registration API', timeSpent: 4, category: 'Backend', type: 'task'},
{id: 235, title: 'Create user registration UI', timeSpent: 8, category: 'Frontend', type: 'task'},
{id: 237, title: 'User sign-in via Google UI', timeSpent: 3.5, category: 'Frontend', type: 'task'},
{id: 238, title: 'User sign-in via Google API', timeSpent: 5, category: 'Backend', type: 'task'},
{id: 241, title: 'Fix account linking', timeSpent: 5, category: 'Backend', type: 'bug'},
{id: 250, title: 'Fix wrong time created on new record', timeSpent: 1, category: 'Backend', type: 'bug'},
{id: 262, title: 'Fix sign-in failed messages', timeSpent: 2, category: 'Frontend', type: 'bug'}
];

let taskFilterUi = tasks.filter((elem) => {
  return elem.title.match( /(^|\s)UI($|\s)/ );
});

let taskMapUI = taskFilterUi.map((task) => {
  return "Заголовок:" + "  " + task.title;
});

console.log(taskMapUI);
```